# Why does Discrete Fourier Transform of $\sin^2(x)$ seemingly have an extra frequency component compared to $|\sin x|$?

Tags: fourier-transform, python

I'm trying to better understand Fourier Transform.

In python, I took the fourier transform of $\sin^2(x)$ and $|\sin(x)|$ and plotted the absolute value of the coefficients to see which frequencies are in the signal. The plot of $\sin^2(x)$ makes sense to me. But I'm wondering why do I see an extra value at the fourth frequency bin for $|\sin(x)|$?

I mean both signals have the same frequency, so why is the Fourier Transform telling me that there is a component of another frequency?

[plot |sin(x)|](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np2Dm.png)[plot sin^2(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et9F2.png)

Comment: Neither one is a pure sine wave, so they both have frequency components besides the fundamental frequency. The Fourier transform represents a signal as the sum of pure sine waves, so different signals have different Fourier transforms.

Comment: Right. But in my specific example, don't both |sin(x)| and sin^2(x) have the same frequency, namely 2? Why is there an extra amplitude by 4 in the power spectrum of |sin(x)|?

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing to say that the functions "have the same frequency", since both are composed of multiple sinusoidal frequency *components*, which are what the Fourier transform shows you. Both functions do have the same *period*, which is half that of $\sin x$; this implies that all of their odd-frequency components will be $0$, but it doesn't imply anything about the even-frequency components above 2, which reflect the shape of the periodic signal.

Looking at the (non-transformed) plots, you can see that the difference $|\sin x|-\sin^2x$ oscillates four times between $0$ and a fixed positive value. This means to get from $\sin^2$ to $|\sin x|$, you need to add a signal of the form $a+b\sin(4x)$. The $a$ part increases the frequency-0 component of the Fourier transform and the $b$ part increases the frequency-4 component.

Comment: Hey thanks so much Karl. I guess I still need to better understand the FT. But stepping back, don't both functions have a frequency of 2 on the interval plotted (just by simple inspection)? And isn't that why both have a positive value in the second frequency bin in the power spectrum?

Comment: That's right, and it's also why they both have zero values in all the odd-numbered bins. (If they didn't, then the first half of the graph would differ from the second half.) But I think your confusion comes from thinking in terms of "the frequency" of a function instead of thinking of a function as a sum of potentially several frequency components. Note that $\sin(2x)$ has the same period as $\sin(2x)+\sin(4x)$. The Fourier transform tells you all the frequency components, not just the lowest one.